# Applying pagesetup for whole word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word document with 120 sections. I wrote a simple Do Until loop to apply pagesetup as shown in the code. It takes little over 2 mins to loop through all the sections, which is too long. Is there any faster way to solve this issue?

```
Dim oSecRange As Word.Range
Dim iSecCounter As Long
iSecCounter = 0
Do
    Set oSecRange = oDoc.Sections(iSecCounter + 1).Range
    Application.StatusBar = "Adjusting HEADER & FOOTER distance & Page Margins - " & 
    Application.Round((iSecCounter / oDoc.Sections.Count) * 100, 0) & "% Completed."
    oSecRange.PageSetup.HeaderDistance = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    oSecRange.PageSetup.FooterDistance = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    oSecRange.PageSetup.LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    oSecRange.PageSetup.RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    oSecRange.PageSetup.TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    iSecCounter = iSecCounter + 1
Loop Until iSecCounter = oDoc.Sections.Count
```

Comment: Does it work? What is the problem with this code?

Comment: It works. Thought it takes too long (2 mins for 120 sections) to loop through all the sections. Wondering if there is any other method to code this.

Comment: Scan the document to ensure that each section is linked to the previous section. Then you only need to do the page setup once.

Comment: Try commenting out the status bar updates and add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning. Does that make any difference? And test using `For Each sec in oDoc.Sections` instead of a`Do`-loop. Theoretically, it is possible to use `oDoc.PageSetup...` instead of addressing each section individually, but this can cause problems when a document is large, but you can try it...

Comment: @Freeflow Linking to previous is only for header and footer *content*. It has no relation to margin settings.

Comment: @CindyMeister thanks for the clarification.  In this case, if all pages need the same margins, I'd just do a select all and then set the margin.

Comment: @CindyMeister I do have application.screenupdating = false at the beginning of the code . For Each Sec in oDoc.sections and  Do loop takes around the same time to run. I tried oDoc.Pagesetup and it gives a "rt error 4608: value Out of range error".                                          
          oDoc.PageSetup.HeaderDistance = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)

Comment: If you're not getting this error with the original code, on the same document, then you may be running into that "oddness" working with the entire document can cause. In that case the only other thing that occurs to me would be to work with a `Range` object the covers multiple `Section`s. You can test to find out what's optimal. An example: `Set rngSecs = oDoc.Sections(1).Range : rngSecs.End = oDoc.Sections(10).Range.End : With rngSecs.PageSetup` and then sections 11 through 20, and so on. Whatever number of sections gives an optimal speed (assuming the approach works without error).

Answer (score 0):

If you need all pages to be the same and you don't have to consider orientation then the code below will do the job.

```
With ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdCommentsStory).PageSetup

    .HeaderDistance = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .FooterDistance = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    '.BottomMargin= Application.InchesToPoints(0.25) ?

End With
```

If you have different page requirements and also have different orientations then you may need to work section by section.  In this case turn off screen updating before you start and then turn it on when you finish.  (Application.ScreenUpdating=false/true)  This will stop word taking the time to reformat your document each time you make a change to a page format parameters (e.g 5 reformats for each section in your original code).

Comment: I get a runtime error '5941': Requested member of the collection does not exist at line...storyranges.pagesetup. I'm running this from excel and i have everything linked to word object. Not sure what i'm missing.

Comment: Because I'm getting old and my fingers don't always do what I think they've done.  Replace 'wdCommentsStory' with 'wdMainTextStory'

Comment: Thanks. Now i get a 4608 error: Value out of range in the .headerDistance line. This is the same error i get when i do a activedocument.pagesetup. Did the above code run fine for you?

Comment: Yes.  Your error may mean that the printer installed as the default printer doesn't support the margin size you have set.